# Mocking service method for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to test `GetUserDetails` from UserTest class. `test` user has data, but test always returns null for `getUser`. Do I write test correctly? Any suggestion how to use service method here in a rigth way

```
[TestClass]
public class UserTest
{
    IUserService _userService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _userService = new Mock<IUserService>().Object; 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void getUserInfo()
    {
        var getUser = _userService.GetUserDetails("test"); //it's not null, user has data

        Assert.IsNotNull(getUser); //always null
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to setup you MockService to return the things you want to receive, use the `Setup` method of the mock-object.
also, i think you understood the concept wrong. 
you should test the unit, and mock the dependencies your unit requires, when you test the mock, you do not gain any sensible test result

so in short. that test doesnt make any sense. test the real implementation of userservice `_userService = new <your real class>(<your mocked dependencies>)`

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer As far as I am concerned, your comment should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing `GetUserDetails` you should not mock the service it is part of.

Your test should look more like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetUser()
{
    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehaviour.Strict);
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IMyRepo>(MockBehaviour.Strict);

    var beingTested = new UsersService(
        logger: mockLogger.Object
        userRepo: mockRepo.Object,
        ...);

    mockRepo.Setup( r => r.GetUserFromDb("test")).Returns( new UserDetails(...));

    var getUser = beingTested.GetUserDetails("test"); 

    Assert.IsNotNull(getUser);
}
```