# C# Need help writing unit tests

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I need some help writing unit tests for the following class

```
 public class ImportTechnologiesScheduled
    {
        private readonly ISqlImporter _sqlImporter;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ITelemetryAgent _telemetryAgent;
        public ImportTechnologiesScheduled(ISqlImporter sqlImporter, IConfiguration configuration, ITelemetryAgent telemetryAgent)
        {
            _sqlImporter = sqlImporter;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _telemetryAgent = telemetryAgent;
        }

        [FunctionName("ImportTechnologiesScheduled")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            try
            {
                var importRequest = new ImportRequest
                {
                    ItemType = ItemTypes.Technology,
                    CosmosContainerId = _configuration["CosmosTechnologyContainer"]
                };
                await _sqlImporter.ImportAsync<Technology>(importRequest);
                _telemetryAgent.TrackEvent("ImportTechnologiesScheduled_Executed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _telemetryAgent.TrackExceptionEvent("ImportTechnologiesScheduled_Failed", ex, new Dictionary<string, string>());
                throw ex;
            }
```

I honestly have no idea where to start besides the basic file structure of:

```
 public class ImportTechnologiesScheduledTests
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task ()
        {
         //Arrange
            var mockRepo = new Mock<IDecarbonizationToolRepository>();
        

        //Act
        
        //Assert

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should check whether the methods of `_sqlImporter` and `_telemetryAgent` have been called with the correct parameters. Use a mock for this.

Comment: @SomeBody they have been called with the correct parameters, thanks

Comment: You know the general pattern of unit tests (arrange, act, assert), and you know how to make a mock. What don't you understand that's left to do? Construct the class using mocked objects? Inspect the results of the method under test?

Answer (score 1):

you should test the unit, and mock the dependencies. your result would look something like this:

```
public class ImportTechnologiesScheduledTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task ()
    {
     //Arrange
        
        var mockImporter = new Mock<ISqlImporter>();
        var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
        var mockTelemetryAgent= new Mock<Telemetry>(/*MockMode.Strict if you want*/);

        //here, you setup the mocks so that they return whatever you expect in your usecase, or raise exceptions when they dont receive what they should receive
       //ie.  mockConfig.Setup(c => c.Getter("test")).Returns(<result>));
       //... recommend a strict mockmode that prevents you from forgetting things
       
        //create your unit, with fake dependencies
        var underTest = new ImportTechnologiesScheduled(
          sqlImporter: mockImporter.Object,
          configuration: mockConfig.Object,
          telemetryAgent: mockTelemetryAgent.Object
        );

    //Act
    /* if you had a result var myResult = */ underTest.Run(...);
    //Assert
      
     //check your result here with asserts, or let the mocks assert things, like bein called correctly

    }
```

look deeper into the Setup methods of Mock objects, it provides really good features.

also have a look at [Mocking service method for unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420408/mocking-service-method-for-unit-test#comment126239328_71420408)

also, that question might be a duplicate